# Does bootstrap.min.JS conflict with chart.min,js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, chart.js

I am creating an admin page for customer support and I included a fancy chart to display some info on the home page. That went well but when I added tab panes to the page and reloaded it, the chart grows downwards and causes the page to keep scrolling, only stops after changing tabs and then coming up but with changes to the html file then reloading, starts again.
The chart caption( or legend?) is messed up as well, just shows basic text with no formatting whatsoever as specified in the CSS.
*I can't post the image for some reason*.
It is very irritating and I wanted to know what can possibly be causing this. I will just post all the scripts I am using and the code for the chat as well. I want to know if this is potentially caused by conflicting JS files.

```
    <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    
    <div class="col-lg-4 d-flex flex-grow">
                                <div class="row ">
                                  <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-12 grid-margin stretch-card">
                                    <div class="card bg-primary card-rounded">
                                      <div class="card-body pb-0">
                                        <h4 class="card-title card-title-dash text-white mb-4">Total Crops</h4>
                                        <div class="row">
                                          <div class="col-sm-4">
                                            <p class="status-summary-ight-white mb-1">For this month</p>
                                            <h2 class="text-info">20</h2>
                                          </div>
                                          <div class="col-sm-8">
                                            <div class="status-summary-chart-wrapper pb-4">
                                              <canvas id="status-summary"></canvas>
                                            </div>
                                          </div>
                                        </div>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-12 grid-margin stretch-card">
                                    <div class="card card-rounded">
                                      <div class="card-body">
                                        <div class="row">
                                          <div class="col-sm-6">
                                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center mb-2 mb-sm-0">
                                              <div class="circle-progress-width">
                                                <div id="noDisease" class="progressbar-js-circle pr-2"></div>
                                              </div>
                                              <div>
                                                <p class="text-small mb-2">No Diseases</p>
                                                <h4 class="mb-0 fw-bold">70%</h4>
                                              </div>
                                            </div>
                                          </div>
                                          <div class="col-sm-6">
                                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                                              <div class="circle-progress-width">
                                                <div id="withDisease" class="progressbar-js-circle pr-2"></div>
                                              </div>
                                              <div>
                                                <p class="text-small mb-2">With Diseases</p>
                                                <h4 class="mb-0 fw-bold">30%</h4>
                                              </div>
                                            </div>
                                          </div>
                                        </div>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
        <script src="/template/vendors/chart.js/Chart.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/template/vendors/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/template/vendors/progressbar.js/progressbar.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/template/assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/template/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"></script>
        <script src="/template/js/jquery.cookie.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/template/js/dashboard.js"></script>
        <script src="/template/js/Chart.roundedBarCharts.js"></script>

    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can observe that you are using `bootstrap` css file into your script tag something like this -

```
<script src="/template/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"></script>
```

We can't use stylesheets inside script tags, to load stylesheet/ CSS we need link tag as and use it inside head tag-

```
<link href="/template/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Please use this as a stylesheet and use `link` tag for the same.
I hope it will start to work.

let me know please in case i can help you further.
Thanks.

Comment: I have placed it inside the link as a stylesheet, yes  but the chart is still stretching downwards.

Comment: can you please check that is bootstrap styling is loading properly or not ? You can check it by looking into the network requests .